# Compare JDBC Request results with JSON HTTP Request Response array data

Tags: mysql, json, jmeter, beanshell

I have a JDBC Request that contains a query like:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, START_DATE, COMPLETE_DATE,          
        NUMBER_OF_FINDINGS FROM CUSTOMER ORDER BY START_DATE;
```

This returns 70 records.  Now, I have a JSON HTTP Request to pull this same data in the same order from a grid in a webpage.  I get 70 records.  How can I compare each value in the arrays from the DB and the array from the JSON response?  I've found info about how to check a single value but not comparing all values between the 2 datasets.  I've tried the below BeanShell Assertion but it is not working.  I tried using a BSF PostProcessor to put the JSON values into variables but that did not work either.  My Debug Sampler is showing that it is getting the values but does not seem to be comparing them.  Any ideas/thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
String json_customerId = vars.get("customer_id");
String json_customerName = vars.get("customer_name");
String json_startedOn = vars.get("started_on");
String json_completedOn = vars.get("completed_on");
String json_numberOfFindings = vars.get("number_of_findings");
String db_customerId = vars.get("customer_id");
String db_customerName = vars.get("customer_name");
String db_startedOn = vars.get("started_on");
String db_completedOn = vars.get("completed_on");
String db_numberOfFindings = vars.get("number_of_findings");

int intN = 0

For (intN=0; intN=totalItems; intN++)
    if (json_customerId[intN].equals(db_customer_id[intN]))
    {
        Failure = false;
        print("counts match" + json_customerId + db_customer_id); 
    } else {
        Failure = true;
        FailureMessage = "Difference detected, json_result: " + 
                       json_customerID >+ " and db_result: " +  db_customer_id;
    }
```

Comment: I'd personally do this way in Java. 1) Create Customer class with @override equals method 2) load data from JSON and MySQL 3) compare two objects of Customer class using equals. But to fix your code, 1) put `Failure = false` before For loop 2) remove your `Failure = false;` in the if condition 3) (OPTIONAL) break after `Failure = true;` I assume that if one of fields in 70 records does not match, it should be "Failure" true.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. you're using [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) which doesn't seem correct to me as Select query result usually doesn't look like a string.

This approach to compare strings - `json_customerId[intN]` will cause Beanshell Assertion failure as string is not of array type.

I would suggest using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) configuration to inspect variable values from MySQL and JSON. If you fail to determine the right option - update your question with JDBC Sampler and JSON Path Extractor configurations and resulting JMeter Variables values you want to compare.

For the time being here some reference links:

- [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)
- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/)

Comment: so the code I used works for a total row count (see below) but does not seem to work for an array of data.  I'm new to this so I'm sure I could be doing something wrong.  I thought I'd have to put each value into a variable and then compare the db variable and the json variable and they should match.  For reference, here's what works for a single total value:

Comment: 'String json_result = vars.get("totalItems");
String db_result = vars.get("db_count_1");

//int json_result = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("totalItems").trim());
//int db_result = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("db_count_1").trim());

if (json_result.equals(db_result))
{
    Failure = false;
    print("counts match" + json_result + db_result); 
}

else
{
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "Difference detected, json_result: " + json_result + " and db_result: " +     db_result;
}'

Comment: The thing is, I never know how many rows will be returned so I cant declare variables like i did with the one result in the above code (db_count_1).